# Does anybody have an idea about zip-archive recovery using partly downloaded archive and archive contents?

Tags: data-recovery, zip, bittorrent, archiving

Does anybody have an idea how to recover zip-archive using partly downloaded archive and archive contents from another source? Use case: become a seed on an old torrent.

Comment: In most torrent applications you would import the torrent, let it prepare all the file outputs and then stop the torrent. Then you would overwrite the output, and tell the torrent application to verify the files. That should work out what blocks of the output are valid and upon restarting the torrent it will download only the necessary parts.

Comment: Zip files are sequences of individually compressed files, you should be able to recover those that are in the undamaged part. [Here](https://www.hanshq.net/zip.html) is a detailed discussion of the format, and a (simple) program that should help you start hacking...